# Query takes too long with index created - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I've got around 1M of documents more or less like this one:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5461c8f0426f727f16000000")
    "ec" : 9,
    "ai" : 9390448,
    "f" : [ 
        {
            "t" : "ry",
            "v" : 1994
        }, 
        {
            "t" : "g",
            "v" : [ 
                "Crime", 
                "Drama"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "t" : "ml",
            "v" : "English"
        }, 
        {
            "t" : "k",
            "v" : "movie"
        }, 
        {
            "t" : "rel",
            "v" : true
        }
    ]
}
```

I have the necessity of making queries like these:

```
db.items.find(
    {
        $and:[
        {f:{$elemMatch:{t:"ml", v:{$in:["English", "Spanish", "French", "German"]}}}}, 
        {f:{$elemMatch:{t:"rel", v:true}}},
                {f:{$elemMatch:{t:"k", v:"movie"}}},
                {f:{$elemMatch:{t:"ry", v:{$gte:1980}}}},
                {f:{$elemMatch:{t:"g", v:{$in:["Thriller"]}}}},

        ]

        }).sort({ai: -1}).limit(12)
```

And like this:

```
db.items.find(
        {
            $and:[
            {f:{$elemMatch:{t:"ml", v:{$in:["English", "Spanish", "French", "German"]}}}}, 
            {f:{$elemMatch:{t:"rel", v:true}}},
                    {f:{$elemMatch:{t:"k", v:"movie"}}},
                    {f:{$elemMatch:{t:"ry", v:{$gte:1980}}}},
                    {f:{$elemMatch:{t:"g", v:{$in:["Thriller"]}}}},

            ]

            }).sort({ec: -1}).limit(12)
```

Note the sorting difference.

I created the following index:

```
{
    "f.t" : 1,
    "f.v" : 1,
    "ec" : -1,
    "ai" : -1
}
```

Therefore, I thought I could query including always `ec`. Even if I just wanted to sort with `ai` I could introduce `{ec: {$gte: 0}}` (`ec` has 0 or greater value for ALL documents).

If I make the following query, it uses the index and everything is ok:

```
db.items.find(
    {
        $and:[
        {f:{$elemMatch:{t:"ml", v:{$in:["English", "Spanish", "French", "German"]}}}}, 
        {f:{$elemMatch:{t:"rel", v:true}}},
                {f:{$elemMatch:{t:"k", v:"movie"}}},
                {f:{$elemMatch:{t:"ry", v:{$gte:1980}}}},
                {f:{$elemMatch:{t:"g", v:{$in:["Thriller"]}}}},
                {ec: {$gte: 0}}
        ]

        }).limit(12)
```

However, when I introduce sorting with `ai` it gets tremendously slow and 'never' comes back:

```
db.items.find(
    {
        $and:[
        {f:{$elemMatch:{t:"ml", v:{$in:["English", "Spanish", "French", "German"]}}}}, 
        {f:{$elemMatch:{t:"rel", v:true}}},
                {f:{$elemMatch:{t:"k", v:"movie"}}},
                {f:{$elemMatch:{t:"ry", v:{$gte:1980}}}},
                {f:{$elemMatch:{t:"g", v:{$in:["Thriller"]}}}},
                {ec: {$gte: 0}}
        ]

        }).sort({ai: -1}).limit(12)
```

I don't quite understand this behavior. I'm guessing the only way is to create two different indexes for this.

Ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The [`documentation`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/#sort-and-non-prefix-subset-of-an-index) states:

> An index can support sort operations on a non-prefix subset of the index key pattern. To do so, the query must include **equality** conditions on all the prefix keys that precede the sort keys.

AFAIK, `$gte` doesn't count as an equality condition; only `{ <field>: <value> }` does.

Using multiple indexes should fix your problem:

```
{ "f.t" : 1, "f.v" : 1, "ec" : -1 }
{ "ai" : -1 }
```

(untested)